# User Permission Log in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, user

I need to view the timestamp when a User has been added to the Sharepoint group and by whom. Can anyone help me with how this can be checked in UI or through powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audit report log will achieve your goal : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131

Or you can start a workflow or some Event Receiver .

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Audit Logs can provide you such reports out of the box.

1. Go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Configure Audit Settings
2. Enable auditing for changes in users and permissions
3. Go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Audit Log Reports
4. Save Security Settings Audit report in SP library of your choice
5. Download the report from the library chosen in step 4